# Exporting Base64 image data / Canvas to PNG, JPG and PDF in GWT

Tags: image, gwt, canvas

Here is my first time that I want to raise my issue here. As the title now I have a trouble with exporting a base64 image data to PNG, JPG, and PDF in GWT so I need your help from you. Let I give you an overview what I want to do:

Please have a look here: http://testingqr.appspot.com/ This is my app to generate a qrcode. After process of customization the Qrcode, I want to export the QR code in the canvas to png,jpg and pdf. To do that I will add 3 buttons are "Export to PDF" "Export to PNG" "Export to JPG" after press on each of these button, a Download Dialog will appear (Save as dialog) to let user choosing the location they want to save to and the extension of the file too (Such as C:\test.png)

I already use dataToURL function to get a base64. I used CanvasTo Image library from this link http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/canvas2image/ But it will download the image from canvas with no Save as dialog and no extension in FF or chrome (IE does not support for HTML5 Canvas). So that I cant export PNG and JPG. This is my first problem.

The second problem is exporting PDF in GWT, I want to work with an open source library. I tried PDF Box http://pdfbox.apache.org/userguide/cookbook.html But now it just supports the JPG type. I want something that convert to PDF from base64. Do you have idea to help me do exporting to PDF process. What I want is after I press on "Export to PDF" button, a dialog will appear to let me save the QRcode in PDF file to my local location.

So thank you all for any help. Have a nice day.

Michael Vu